# Linking progressbar with datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am running a windows forms project. on the form there is a datagridview, a progress bar, a textbox and two 2 buttons.

The two buttons are used to navigate through the records(one for next record and the other for previous record) the textbox displays the record that is being currently viewed.

How can I link the progress with the database or in this case the datagridview and when the next button is pressed it increments and when the previous button is clicked it decrements and also the progress to be fully filled when the last record is reached ?

I think I have got an idea on how to this , i think i will have to set the minimum value to be the lowest record number and the maximum to be the highest record number. Then set the progress bar to the current record number being viewed. but i don't how can implement this.

Now I am not asking for anyone to do or to write the entire code for me , if you can just please show me how to do it i will be happy.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have record navigation functionality for `DataGridView` use a `BindingNavigator` and `BindingSource`. The `BindgingNavigator` has buttons to navigate to first, next, previous and last records and also displays the current record number and total record number. With this you might not need the `ProgressBar`.

In case you require `ProgressBar`, subscribe to the `BindingNavigator.MoveNextItem.Click` event and in the handler increment the progress bar. Similarly use the `MovePreviousItem.Click` event for decrementing the progress bar. You got the idea...right?

Sample Code for using `BindingNavigator` and `BindingSource`

```
BindingNavigator bn = new BindingNavigator(true); 
// add the navigator to your form control collection
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = GetFromDB(); // It can be a DataTable or DataSet
bn.BindingSource = bs;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```